# Java TicTacToe Constructor

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a TicTacToe GUI and came across this Constructor while looking for help. What does (Tile... tiles) do here?

```
    private class Combo{
    private Tile[] tiles;
    public Combo(Tile... tiles) {
        this.tiles = tiles;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The three dots in (Tile... tiles) is called 'varargs'. It means you can pass the array of tiles without explicitly creating the array when calling the constructor.

You can call the constructor like this.

```
Combo combo = new Combo(tile1, tile2);
```

If the constructor was written without 'varargs', like this,

```
public Combo(Tile[] tiles) {
        this.tiles = tiles;
    }
```

then you have to call the constructor by explicitly creating a new array

```
Combo combo = new Combo(new Tile[]{tile1, tile2});
```

Answer (score 1):

> What does (Tile... tiles) do here?

It is commonly known as **Varargs** or **variadic** functions. This is a method which take an arbitrary number of values required. Varargs are available since Java 5. It basically replaces the use of an array as a parameter of the function when you don't know the number of arguments needed.

The syntax is : **standard type declaration** (String, Object, int, ...) followed by an **ellipsis** (the three dots).

A very common example can be a sum method with an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
static int sum(int... args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int arg : args) {
        sum += arg;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

In your case this syntax means that the **Combo()** method can be called with **zero** or **more arguments**.

Some links for a better understanding:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/
- https://studiofreya.com/java/how-to-use-java-varargs/